# Remove extra <br>'s from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to remove unnecessary strings: `<br>`, `<br/>` and `<br />` from a string, that might contain many of them in row. Example:

`This is a string with <br><br/> many <br/><br> newlines. <br><br><br /><br> But it's ok <br> to have one!`

I would like it to become this:

`This is a string with <br> many <br> newlines. <br> But it's ok <br> to have one!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
str = str.replace(/<\/?br\s*\/?>\s*(<\/?br\s*\/?>)+/ig, '<br>');
```

Comment: This also removes any space after duplicate `br`s (also, ignores `br`s with attributes)

Comment: The downvotes are most likely purely ideological because you used regex to manipulate HTML

Comment: Should perhaps make it case insensitive just to be safe.

Comment: @cookiemonster who uses uppercase tags nowadays anyways?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Does it really matter? We're talking about adding the letter `i` to the regex. So why not? ;-p

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "This is a string with <br><br/> many <br/><br> newlines. <br><br><br /><br> But it's ok <br> to have one!";
var cleaned = str.replace(/(<br\s?\/?>\s?)+/g,"<br/> ");
```

And now the bad news, it is really a bad idea to match HTML tags with a regular expression. See this question: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

An alternative would be to set it to a element, loop through the nodes and remove the tags.

Quick and rough code, did not do a lot of testing on this

```
function removeDupeBrs (elem) {
    var childrenNodes = elem.childNodes;
    for (var i = childrenNodes.length-1; i>=0 ; i--) {
        var cn = childrenNodes[i];
        if (cn.nodeType===1 && cn.tagName==="BR") {
            var next = childrenNodes[i-1];
            if (next && next.nodeType===1 && next.tagName==="BR") {
                elem.removeChild(cn);                
            }
        }
    }    
}

var str = "This is a string with <br><br/> many <br/><br> newlines. <br><br><br /><br> But it's ok <br> to have one!";
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = str;
removeDupeBrs(div);
console.log(div.innerHTML);
```

Comment: How's this different from Dystroy's answer?

Comment: @JanDvorak Because I wrote the answer when there was not an answer and posted it...

Comment: but why did you post it when Dystroy's answer is exactly the same?

Comment: @JanDvorak BECAUSE I DID NOT SEE THE ANSWER! IT WAS NOT THERE! Do you not understand how time works?

Comment: You are right about the alternative approach; if you show it in code, you deserve an upvote from me. (no need to shout, by the way; if I didn't expect an answer, I wouldn't ask)

Comment: May want to turn the last `\s?` into `\s*` just in case there happens to be two or more spaces between a couple of `<br>` tags.